# How to use this component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-number-format

Took this component from MUI docs

```
export interface CustomProps {
    onChange: (event: { target: { name: string; value: string } }) => void;
    name: string;
}
  const NumberFormatCustom = React.forwardRef<NumberFormat, CustomProps>(
  function NumberFormatCustom(props, ref) {
    const { onChange, ...other } = props;

    return (
      <NumberFormat
        {...other}
        getInputRef={ref}
        onValueChange={(values) => {
          onChange({
            target: {
              name: props.name,
              value: values.value,
            },
          });
        }}
        thousandSeparator
        isNumericString
        prefix="$"
      />
    );
  },
);
```

then it is used like this

```
      <TextField
        label="react-number-format"
        value={values.numberformat}
        onChange={handleChange}
        name="numberformat"
        id="formatted-numberformat-input"
        InputProps={{
          inputComponent: NumberFormatCustom as any, //Here
        }}
        variant="standard"
      />
```

Now the question is how do I pass props to `NumberFormat`? How can I even use it `<NumberFormatCustom name='???' onChange={???}></NumberFormatCustom>`

Comment: did you tried `InputProps ={{inputComponent: <NumberFormatCustom name='???' />}}` ?

Comment: Yes, but I need also to pass onChange prop and I have no idea what I need to pass in it